# Unable To Get JSON Data With Scrapy request

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, screen-scraping

Hi Here is the actual URL To send Data:

```
https://eltamd.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

And Here Is The Form Data:

```
address:4000
formdata:nameSearch=&addressInput=4000&addressInputCity=&addressInputState=&addressInputCountry=&cat=&catsel_0=&ignore_radius=0
lat:32.7210676
lng:-97.38795720000002
name:
options[address_autocomplete]:none
options[append_to_search]:
options[city]:
options[city_selector]:hidden
options[country]:
options[country_selector]:hidden
options[cron_import_recurrence]:none
options[cron_import_timestamp]:
options[csv_clear_messages_on_import]:1
options[csv_duplicates_handling]:skip
options[csv_file_url]:
options[csv_skip_geocoding]:0
options[default_comments]:0
options[default_page_status]:draft
options[default_trackbacks]:0
options[disable_initial_directory]:0
options[distance_unit]:miles
options[dropdown_style]:none
options[google_map_style]:
options[ignore_radius]:0
options[immediately_show_locations]:0
options[initial_radius]:10000
options[installed_version]:5.0.4
options[label_directions]:Directions
options[label_email]:Email
options[label_fax]:Fax: 
options[label_phone]:Phone: 
options[label_website]:Website
options[load_data]:0
options[loading_indicator]:
options[map_center]:United States
options[map_center_lat]:39.809734
options[map_center_lng]:-98.555620
options[map_domain]:maps.google.com
options[map_end_icon]:https://eltamd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/gray-pin-30x30.png
options[map_home_icon]:https://eltamd.com/wp-content/plugins/store-locator-le/images/icons/box_yellow_home.png
options[map_region]:us
options[map_type]:roadmap
options[message_bad_address]:Could not locate this address. Please try a different location.
options[message_no_results]:No locations found.<br>Please contact us at <a href="tel:800-633-8872">800-633-8872</a> for more information.
options[no_autozoom]:0
options[no_homeicon_at_start]:1
options[page_template]:
options[pages_read_more_text]:
options[pages_replace_websites]:1
options[permalink_flush_needed]:0
options[permalink_starts_with]:store-page
options[prepend_permalink_blog]:1
options[prevent_new_window]:1
options[selector_behavior]:use_both
options[state]:
options[state_selector]:hidden
options[tag_autosubmit]:0
options[tag_dropdown_first_entry]:
options[tag_label]:
options[tag_label ]:
options[tag_output_processing]:hide
options[tag_selections]:
options[tag_selector]:none
options[tag_show_any]:0
options[territory]:
options[territory_selector]:
options[use_nonces]:0
options[use_same_window]:1
options[use_sensor]:0
options[zoom_level]:4
options[zoom_tweak]:0
radius:20
tags:
action:csl_ajax_search
```

I Tried sending this using an online service `https://reqbin.com/` but unable to retrive json data rather giving me 400 error code.

I tried with scrapy FormRequest but that also gives me 400 error code.
Is there anyway that I can retrive data properly?
I have not yet tried with requests

Comment: You have posted some text, but no **code** -- what _code_ are you using to try and send those values?

Comment: Well I Tried That ON reqbin.com. Maybe reqbin is sending text.Can You try this on your side and let me know?